# Filter oData with array of custom attribute ( $expand ) and use $filter for a specific attribute

Tags: rest, filter, odata, sapui5, expand

With this structure of the oData v2 result from a GetEntitySet (JSON Format)

```
{
d: {
__count: "3215",
result : [
 {
   City    : 'NewYork',
   Country : 'USA',
   CustomAttributeData : {
     results : [ 
      {   Name: "custom1",
          Value: "20220707"
      },
      {   Name: "custom2",
          Value: "20220710"
      },
      {   Name: "custom3",
          Value: "20220713"
      }
    ]
  }
 },
 {
   City    : 'Rome',
   Country : 'ITALY',
   CustomAttributeData : {
     results : [ 
      {   Name: "custom1",
          Value: "20220702"
      },
      {   Name: "custom2",
          Value: "20220710"
      },
      {   Name: "custom3",
          Value: "20220710"
      }
    ]
  }
 },
 {
   City    : 'Tokyo',
   Country : 'JAPAN',
   CustomAttributeData : {
     results : [ 
      {   Name: "custom1",
          Value: "20220710"
      },
      {   Name: "custom2",
          Value: "20220711"
      },
      {   Name: "custom3",
          Value: "20220710"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
],
}
}
....

]
```

I want to filter all the cities with the CustomAttributeData custom2=20220710 (all but not Tokyo). What is the correct uri ?

```
https://xxxxxx?$expand=CustomAttributeData$filter=CustomAttributeData/Value eq '20220710'
```

This one is of course wrong because consider Tokyo too.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OData V2, it's not possible. You'll need to use the [**`any`** lambda operator](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc371341806)* for your filter which is available only in OData V4.

---

* See also this [SAP Developer video section](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9JyaPYtWKs&t=2730s) which explains `any` and `all` operators for OData V4 filters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I solved it with the standard documentation. They were a CustomAttribute of the [API TaskCollection in NEO](https://help.sap.com/doc/93dba1b02dba415c9e868d81c4ff86c0/Cloud/en-US/wfs-core-api-docu-tcm.html#:~:text=Filter%20predicates%20which,the%20%27TaskDefinitionID%27%20attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out Tokyo by using `ne` operator in `$filter` query.

```
$filter=City ne 'Tokyo'
```

Added to your query

```
https://xxxxxx?$expand=CustomAttributeData&$filter=City ne 'Tokyo' and CustomAttributeData/Value eq '20220710'
```